# Why doesn't this symmetry argument hold?

Tags: probability, contest-math

> A frog sitting at the point $(1, 2)$ begins a sequence of jumps, where
> each jump is parallel to one of the coordinate axes and has length
> $1$, and the direction of each jump (up, down, right, or left) is
> chosen independently at random. The sequence ends when the frog
> reaches a side of the square with vertices $(0,0), (0,4), (4,4),$ and
> $(4,0)$. What is the probability that the sequence of jumps ends on a
> vertical side of the square?

The [solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2020_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_13#Solution_1) exploits symmetry to obtain an answer of $\frac{5}{8}.$ Specifically, the frog has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of ending on a vertical side if the frog is at $(1, 3), (2, 2),$ or $(1, 1)$. This is intuitively true because at these points, the frog is equidistant to a vertical or horizontal side.

Based on this "symmetry" argument, why doesn't the following analogous logic hold true?

The distances to the top, right, bottom, and left sides from $(1,2)$ are $2, 3, 2,$ and $1$, respectively. This means that from $(1, 2)$:

- The probability of ending on the top side is 3/2 the probability of ending on the right side.
- The probability of ending on the top side is equal to the probability of ending on the bottom side.
- The probability of ending on the top side is 1/2 the probability of ending on the left side.

Thus, the probability of ending on either the left or right side is:
$$P(\text{vertical})=\frac{P(\text{L})+P(\text{R})}{P(\text{T})+P(\text{B})+P(\text{L})+P(\text{R})}
=\frac{2P(\text{T})+\frac{2}{3}P(\text{T})}{P(\text{T})+P(\text{T})+2P(\text{T})+\frac{2}{3}P(\text{T})}=\frac{4}{7}.$$

This is different from the actual answer, $\frac{5}{8},$ where the numerator and denominator are both increased by one. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Your inference "The probability of ending on the top side is 3/2 the probability of ending on the right side" is not justified. Symmetry reasonings can tell if two probabilities are equal, otherwise you need some other argument.

Comment: I made the full computation, just out of curiosity, and found: $$P(T)=P(B)={3\over16}, \quad P(L)={59\over112},\quad P(R)={11\over112}.$$